# What is omitted before 'is' in 'New report on gas prices says B.C. drivers still paying more than is justified'?

Tags: sentence-structure

> New report on gas prices says B.C. drivers still paying more than [] is
> justified.

What content can I use to fit the square brackets, 'what', or something else? i.e.

> New report on gas prices says B.C. drivers still paying more than [what] is
> justified.

Comment: Nothing is 'omitted', but, yes, you can put 'what' or 'that which' before 'is justified', if it makes you feel better. The result will be more cumbersome.

Comment: You might say that there is an understood object of *paying* (i.e. paying more money) that could fill the gap indicated by your brackets.

Comment: The only "omitted" word is is the active verb. What the report *actually* says is: *"B.C. drivers **are** still paying more than is justified".*

Comment: Another way would be to repeat the verb: Eating more than [eating] is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> New report on gas prices says B.C. drivers still paying more than is justified.

The fullstop in OP's example led me into thinking something was indeed missing.

Only after searching further did I notice that that example (minus the fullstop) is the title of a video.

Titles are commonly not full sentences.  For that, we can do without, for example, *what*:

> New report on gas prices says B.C. drivers still paying more than (what) is justified

If we want to form a complete sentence, we could either insert **are** or reconstruct the sentence.

> New report on gas prices says B.C. drivers [are] still paying more than (what) is justified.